# Implementing a weighted BFS to find shortest path

Tags: c++, list, graph, weighted

I'm using an adjacency list and my addEdge function looks like this:

```
void Graph::addEdge(int start, int end, int weight)
{
    adj[start].push_back(end); 
}
```

Which would be fine except I need to know the weight of the edge. Just can't wrap my head around it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a class to hold both the weight and endpoint of the edge:

```
class Edge
{
  public:
    int endpoint;
    int weight;
};
```

Naturally, this will require modifications to your Graph; `adj` would need to store `Edge`s rather than `int`s. If that isn't feasible, you could map edges to weights like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > edgeWeights;
```

such that for a given edge u-v, `edgeWeights[u][v]` is the weight of edge u-v.

Similarly, you could also map pairs (i.e. edges) to weights:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> edgeWeights;
```

The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I'd rather use a struct than a class (one word less typing ;)), but aside from that I like your answer.

Comment: Ok so I chose to go with making an Edge struct. However, how would I approach the addEdge method? I would have to make a temporary Edge object, set the target and weight, but then how would it know what those target and weight are connected to?